# access a variable outside a function - swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying yo access a variable outside a function, I tried to declare the variable outside the class but it keeps displaying the initial value in the declaration not the value inside the function, here is my code, I need to access databaseScore

```
func getDatabaseScore()-> Int{
    let ref2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("user").child((user?.uid)!)

    ref2.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if var userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Int] {
            //Do not cast print it directly may be score is Int not string
            var databaseScore = userDict["score"]

        }


    })

    return databaseScore

}
```

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 if this is an answer, please add it as such

Comment: It's the famous *async-trap*. It's impossible to return something form a method containing an asynchronous task.

Comment: Can you please add more code to your question. Particularly, show the enclosing object, and where you call `getDatabaseScore()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment *it's impossible to return something form a method containing an asynchronous task*.

You need a completion block for example

```
func getDatabaseScore(completion: (Int?)->()) {
    let ref2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("user").child((user?.uid)!)

    ref2.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Int] {
            //Do not cast print it directly may be score is Int not string
            completion(userDict["score"])
        }
        completion(nil)
    })
}
```

---

```
getDatabaseScore() { score in 
   guard let score = score else { return }
   // do something with unwrapped "score"
}
```

Comment: this gives me this error: Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values

Comment: My added code cannot crash, most likely the crash occurs in the `let ref2 ...` line. Use optional bindings like in the closure to avoid the crash.

Comment: the app crash here:                 self.getDatabaseScore() { score in
                    // do something with "score"
                    if score! < self.scoreCounter{ //crshes here
                    ref.child("user").child((user?.uid)!).child("score").setValue(self.scoreCounter)
                    }
                }

Comment: `score` is an optional, you have to check it, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an async operation so `getDatabaseScore` returns before `observeSingleEvent` completes. You could look at something like this…

```
class MyClass {

    var databaseScore: Int = 0

    func getDatabaseScore() {

        let ref2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("user").child((user?.uid)!)

        ref2.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in                 
            if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Int] { 
                 print(userDict["score"]) // Confirm you have the a value
                 self.databaseScore = userDict["score"]
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: databaseScore still hold 0, its declaration value

Comment: Maybe `userDict["score"]` contains 0? Try adding a `print` in there to confirm

Comment: Is your object a struct or a class?

Comment: which object do you mean?